# Can I get a zero-based day of the week with zero representing Sunday without using an if statement or ternary operator?

Tags: php, date

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, the format character `'N'` returns the ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week which is 1 - 7 for Monday through Sunday. I was curious if there is something that returns a zero-based numeric representation of the day of the week which is 0 through 6 for Sunday through Saturday. Right now I am using an if statement to change any 7's to 0's but I just wanted to know if there was a shorter way of doing this (not that it's that long, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look a bit farther down th epage. There's the `w` option for 0(sun)-6(sat)

Answer (score 2):

```
 n          | n % 7
------------+-------
1 through 6 | Same
7           | 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Modulus with 7.  `$date = $date % 7;`